# why the python program is reading data just from one sub directories?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a program that does below:

- There are multiple folders which contains JSON file called “installed-files.json”.
- Program is suppose to read the JSON files from each of the sub-folders.
- If the JSON files are there, then convert it into a xlsx format.
- The xlsx format shoud have worksheets named as per the sub-folder name.
  e.g. if the name of the sub folder is CNA, the sheet name shoud be CNA, etc.

Below is the **code snippet**

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import os

def traverse_dir(rootDir, file_name):
    dir_names = []
    for names in os.listdir(rootDir):
        entry_path = os.path.join(rootDir, names)
        if os.path.isdir(entry_path):
            dir_names.append(entry_path)
            for fil_name in dir_names:
                file_path = os.path.join(fil_name, file_name)
                print(file_path)
                if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                    with open(file_path) as jf:
                        data = json.load(jf)
                        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
                        df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
                        new_df = df[df.columns.difference(['SHA256'])]
                        new_df1 = df1[df.columns.difference(['SHA256'])]
                        with pd.ExcelWriter('abc.xlsx') as writer:
                            new_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='BRA', index=False)
                            new_df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='CNA', index=False)
                else:
                    print("file not found")


rootDir = <Full_Path_To_Sub-dirs>
file_name = 'installed-files.json'
traverse_dir(rootDir, file_name)
```

Below is the sample JSON file content

```
[
  {
    "SHA256": "123456",
    "Name": "/system/Home.apk",
    "Size": 99250072
  },
  {
    "SHA256": "987654",
    "Name": "/system/Setup.apk",
    "Size": 86578788
  },
  {
    "SHA256": "457457",
    "Name": "/system/SApp.apk",
    "Size": 72207922
  },
  {
    "SHA256": "747645",
    "Name": "/system/Lib.apk",
    "Size": 57960376
  },
  {
    "SHA256": "368764",
    "Name": "/system/mium.so",
    "Size": 51161376
  },
  {
    "SHA256": "34455",
    "Name": "/system/Smart.apk",
    "Size": 50944780
  },
 {
    "SHA256": "66777",
    "Name": "/system/framework/work.jar",
    "Size": 24772514
  },
  
]
```

Problem Statement:

While the excel sheet is getting created as per the sub folders name(BRA and CNA). But the data is only coming from CNA. I can confirm this, because the JSON file present in both the sub directories had the same data initially. Therefore, to test my use cases I modified the content of  BRA first. But after executing the code those changes were not present the new excel file for any of the two tabs that got created. Hence, I modified the JSON file from the CNA sub-folder. Now, when I execute the program, I could see those modified data in both tabs in the excel file .

Any ideas, why that could be happening?
[image]
I have also attached
- project directory structure screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are writting a excell everytime you found a file and the data you are reading to both data frames is the same because you are getting it from the same JSON file. Also you must check the `new_df1 = df1[df.columns.difference(['SHA256'])]` because you are using the df and the df1, I'm not sure if this is what you wanted.

Either way, here is a working code snippet:

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
import os


def traverse_dir(root: str, file_name: str):
    data_cna = None
    data_bra = None
    for dir in os.listdir(root):
        dir_path = os.path.join(root, dir)
        # Grabs only the directories
        if not os.path.isdir(dir_path):
            continue
        for file in os.listdir(dir_path):
            file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file)

            # Grabs only the files within the directories and with the name passed
            if not os.path.isfile(file_path):
                continue
            if file != file_name:
                continue

            if dir == "CNA":
                with open(file_path) as freader:
                    data_cna = json.load(freader)
            elif dir == "BRA":
                with open(file_path) as freader:
                    data_bra = json.load(freader)
            else:
                # Other directories names are ignored
                continue

    if data_cna is None:
        raise ValueError(f"{file_name} not found in {os.path.join(root, 'CNA')}")
    if data_bra is None:
        raise ValueError(f"{file_name} not found in {os.path.join(root, 'BRA')}")

    df_cna = pd.DataFrame(data_cna)[pd.DataFrame(data_cna).columns.difference(['SHA256'])]
    # Shouldn't this be: df_bra = pd.DataFrame(data_bra)[pd.DataFrame(data_bra).columns.difference(['SHA256'])],
    # I mean replace data_cna difference by data_bra. Check your code.
    df_bra = pd.DataFrame(data_bra)[pd.DataFrame(data_cna).columns.difference(['SHA256'])]

    with pd.ExcelWriter('abc.xlsx') as writer:
        df_cna.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='CNA', index=False)
        df_bra.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='BRA', index=False)


rootDir = "."
file_name = 'installed-files.json'
traverse_dir(rootDir, file_name)
```

CNA JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "SHA256": "123456",
    "Name": "/system/Home.apk",
    "Size": 99250072
  },
  {
    "SHA256": "987654",
    "Name": "/system/Setup.apk",
    "Size": 86578788
  }
]
```

BRA JSON:

```json
[
 {
    "SHA256": "66777",
    "Name": "/system/framework/work.jar",
    "Size": 24772514
  }
]
```

xls output CNA page:
[image]

xls output BRA page:
[image]